# Как скрыть кнопку входа после авторизации в spring security в header

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

В header пытаюсь скрыть кнопку "входа" после авторизации или регистрации пользователя, ничего вообще не получается

```
<div th:fragment="header" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<header class="p-3 mb-3 border-bottom">
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start ">
        <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-dark text-decoration-none">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
            </svg>
        </a>

        <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
            <li><a href="/" class="nav-link px-2 link-secondary">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="/newest" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Новинки</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Товары</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stocks" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">Акции</a></li>
            <li><a href="/aboutUs" class="nav-link px-2 link-dark">О Нас</a></li>
        </ul>

        <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3">
            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-dark" placeholder="Искать..." aria-label="Search">
        </form>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary me-2" onClick='location.href="/login"'>Вход</button>

        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
        </form>
        <a href="/basket" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-dark text-decoration-none">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart3" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .49.598l-1 5a.5.5 0 0 1-.465.401l-9.397.472L4.415 11H13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l.84 4.479 9.144-.459L13.89 4H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

А вот конфиг

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http


                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**", "/registration**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from usr where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from usr u inner join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.username=?");
}
```

А это login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<header th:insert="blocks/header :: header"></header>
<h1>Войдите или зарегистрируйтесь</h1>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>

    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
<a href="/registration"> Add new User</a>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-W8fXfP3gkOKtndU4JGtKDvXbO53Wy8SZCQHczT5FMiiqmQfUpWbYdTil/SxwZgAN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, добавил условие. Я использую thymeleaf

```
<div class="my-2 my-lg-0">
            <ul class="navbar-nav"
                th:switch="${#authentication} ? ${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')} : ${false}">
                <li class="nav-item pull-sm-0">
                    <span th:case="${false}">
                            <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" href="/login">Войдите</a>
                    </span>
                    <span th:case="${true}">
                        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
                            <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Выход"/>
                        </form>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```